# What is this LCD font used in the cover art for for Kraftwerk's "The Model"?

Tags: font-identification

Please help me identify a font or a similar font that I can use. I want a font that makes letters out of dot on a dot matrix font like "THE MODEL" is written on this image:

[image: Kraftwerk - The Model]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was most probably not made using a font file, but [Electronic Highway Sign](http://www.dafont.com/electronic-highway-sign.font) looks a lot like it.

[image]